# Spring security : Getting NoSuchBean Exception error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to the Spring security and i am working on Spring 4 with Spring security 4. I have followed one tutorial to get started but everytime i am getting the error NoSuchBeanDefinition found. 
Somehow i have tried all the suggestions as mentioned on the web and stackoverflow but unable to figure it out.

Following are the snippets of my application to work with Spring-Security.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:web="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      / web-app_3_0.xsd" 
>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
 </session-config>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<annotation-driven />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!--  Testing Database MySQL Local System -->        
<beans:bean id="dataSource"class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tutorzest" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>  


<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition --> 
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.spring.model.User</beans:value>
            <beans:value>com.spring.model.UserRole</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="userDao" class="com.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory"   ref ="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.spring.service.MyUserDetailsService">
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller" /> 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

 </beans:beans>
```

** MyUserDetailsService**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

//get user from the database, via Hibernate
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username)
    throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.xpedia.spring.model.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities =
                                  buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}

// Converts com.mkyong.users.model.User user to
// org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.xpedia.spring.model.User user,
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
        user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles)  

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = 
    new ArrayList <GrantedAuthority>    (setAuths);

    return Result;
}

}
```

After executing I am getting the Following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting
>   bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'userDetailsService' is defined

I may be missing some of the xml configuration. But I am finding it difficult after so many attempts to figure it out. Please help me on this.

Comment: Your security config is root application context whereas the other is child context. You are referencing UserSetailService from child context in root/parent context. Children can refer to parent context beans however it doesn't work other way around. One way to fix this is to scan for controllers only on your servlet context and scan everything except controllers in root context.

Comment: Also remove the security context from your Dispatcher Servlet init param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

To:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ivan .. Your suggestions has worked and it helped me a lot in moving forward.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add bellow code into `servlet-context.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sparkle" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="com.spring.service.MyUserDetailsService">
```